# Running end-to-end tests with TFS, BrowserStack and Selenium

Tags: selenium, browserstack

I use `TFS` and its build definitions to run end-to-end tests with Selenium.

More specifically, I deploy the web app to a test environment and then I run the tests against that test URL with a library called `FluentAutomation` that is based on Selenium. For CI, I use PhantomJS or Google Chrome headless.

Just to be clear, such a test would be, "open the URL / click on a link / assert the URL changed."

My question is - it is possible to use BrowserStack for this purpose? If so, could you please point me to some tutorials or examples? I couldn't find such example on their website.

Comment: I believe you should be able to do this using following syntax: FluentAutomation.SeleniumWebDriver.Bootstrap(
                new Uri("http://hub.browserstack.com/wd/hub/"),  SeleniumWebDriver.Browser.Chrome,TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60)
            );

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should be able to do this using following syntax.

```
FluentAutomation.SeleniumWebDriver.Bootstrap(
            new Uri("http://hub.browserstack.com/wd/hub/"),  SeleniumWebDriver.Browser.Chrome,TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60)
        );
```

You may also need to include Desiredcapabilities and supply it while invoking the above browser instance:

```
DesiredCapabilities capability = new DesiredCapabilities();
capability.SetCapability("browserstack.user", "<BrowserStack_Username>");
capability.SetCapability("browserstack.key", "<BrowserStack_Access_Key>");
capability.SetCapability("browserName","Chrome");
```